# TypeScript inference not working with optional property

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have created a simple example which describes my problem in general and shows the error: [example in TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwCJuGgPACoB8UAvFIVBAB7AQoAmAzlAK5MQBmCKEjUAPxQA3gF8oALlFRGuNNKpiAUMtCQoAITTMIAOSSMIRUhRHKolqImAYI05sABOvAObKJAMljxk6bPImqurQBkbMROTsnDx8jKZaTmgoAMYAFmHGJFAAPlAAMhBoXJlBauDQmkmpGYZZURxGsfwJ2rql2d7mVlAodczSmREkANoAuh7BFQVFJXWRFI3cvC1RbfrzJKopqI5QAEbV6ZnSVcnHdVHdVjZ20gBEh%20e1RvcANBZWfeHS45PKOxQeyeNUyAHUEMA0gBBRiMSF%20TCnI4vYwoNgAW32ECcCWullu9igjxR4MhMLhCNQmHen0s3wgAyg4w%20PTkeGkAEZ-oC9nZiicZgLLmY6dZIXdify5q8ebtgFBpWSobD4YhqRhpIVhUZ8OisTi8WLCQ8lXUISrKer-LS2fIuf8uBwUtaoK4IMBCBKIAAxJxIDEdN5QPTUOgMFgh-omYgACgZgwAlA5nG5RGKnB62E4UL06gA6QlyoEKkEXIxe2zQCjuz3ev0BzKxsuoxMA%20UHUnm8mqqn%20St2KK1ge%20-2BurNrtGC0UtWIjBt3kKs0V71Dj0jhvjoyxlcQRcdvcz3vWzAj9d1qtbptHntW%20eJoA).

```js
type OptionalData<T> = T extends undefined ? {} : { data: T }

type BaseNode<T> = {
    title: string
} & OptionalData<T>

type Nodes<T = undefined> = BranchNode<T> | LeafNode<T>

type BranchNode<T = undefined> = BaseNode<T> & {
    nodes: Nodes<T>[]
}

type LeafNode<T = undefined> = BaseNode<T>

const branchNode: BranchNode = {
    title: "branchNode",
    nodes: []
}

const branchNodeWithAdditional: BranchNode<number> = {
    title: "branchNodeWithAdditional",
    nodes: [],
    data: 1
}

const leafNode: LeafNode = {
    title: "leafNode"
}

const leafNodeWithAdditional: LeafNode<number> = {
    title: "leafNodeWithAdditional",
    data: 1
}

function getTitleFromNode<T, N extends Nodes<T>>(node: N): string {
    return node.title
}

const branchNodeTitle = getTitleFromNode(branchNode)
const branchNodeWithAdditionalTitle = getTitleFromNode(branchNodeWithAdditional)
const leafNodeTitle = getTitleFromNode(leafNode)
const leafNodeWithAdditionalTitle = getTitleFromNode(leafNodeWithAdditional)
```

> Argument of type 'BranchNode' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Nodes'.
>   Type 'BranchNode' is not assignable to type 'BranchNode'.
>     Property 'data' is missing in type 'BranchNode' but required in type '{ data: unknown; }'. *(2345)*

I would really like to understand the core problem of my implementation and why the inference is not working in this case. From my understanding so far, it should infer `BranchNode<undefined>`, but it says it's not assignable to `BranchNode<unknown>`.

I know generics in general but I don't know how to fix this problem.
I tried to solve it with a conditional return type and `as` casts, but then the inference was not working as intended.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I know I could do that, but I want to understand why this case is not working and why it says "Argument of type 'BranchNode<undefined>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BranchNode<unknown>'. Why does it not infer correctly?

Comment: Please [edit] the post to clearly ask the question you're asking, since the closest I can see in the post is "I don't know how to fix this problem", which is different from "why does it not infer correctly"

Comment: (see prev comment) After you do that: it doesn't infer correctly because in the call signature `<T, N extends Nodes<T>>(node: N) => string` there is no inference site for `T`.  `N` can be inferred from `node`, but there is nowhere to infer `T` (constraints do not act as inference sites).  So inference on `T` fails, it falls back to `unknown`, and then because of your constraint, the input is accepted if and only if it's assignable to `Nodes<unknown>`.  Does that fully address the question, or am I still missing something?

Comment: I updated my post, hope its getting clearer now.
Thanks for the answer, it can follow you, but I can't understand why Nodes<unknown> should not accept undefined? It works for number but not for undefined?
Is there a better way I could write this function to get it work?

Comment: `Nodes<unknown>` needs `{data: unknown}`, but `Nodes<undefined>` doesn't have that, so it fails. Does that clear things up? That is a separate question about why inference fails, though.  "Is there a better way...to get it work?" Yes, I suggested `{title: string}` earlier, but then you said you're not really asking how to fix it, but why it doesn't work. Please make sure you're asking a single well-defined question with narrow scope (just *one* of the issues we're talking about here) and let me know if we're on the same page about what the answer should be, and if so, I'll write it up.

Comment: wow, okay that was the trigger point to clearly understand why it fails! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) call signature for `getTitleFromNode()` doesn't have an *inference site* for the `T` type parameter:

```
<T, N extends Nodes<T>>(node: N) => string
```

When you call `getTitleFromNode(node)`, the type argument for `N` will be inferred from the type of `node`.  But `T` has no place from which to be inferred. You might hope that the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `N extends Nodes<T>` might serve as a place from which `T` can be inferred, but it doesn't happen to work that way.  **Generic constraints do not serve as inference sites for other type parameters.**  Note that there was work done at one point that might have changed this, see [microsoft/TypeScript#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234), but it was never merged.

Since there's nothing from which `T` can be inferred, inference fails, and the type argument falls back to its constraint, which is implicitly [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown).

That means `N` is constrained to be assignable to `Nodes<unknown>`, and therefore the call signature is equivalent to

```
<N extends Nodes<unknown>>(node: N) => string;
```

which means it will accept `node` if and only if it's assignable to `Nodes<unknown>`.

---

But by construction of your `Nodes` type, specifically the way you constructed `OptionalData<T>` as

```
type OptionalData<T> = T extends undefined ? {} : { data: T }
```

a `Nodes<unknown>` will require `{data: unknown}`, while a `Nodes<undefined>` does not.  So `Nodes<undefined>` is *not* assignable to `Nodes<unknown>`, and therefore `branchNode` and `leafNode` are unacceptable.

---

Given the example as written here, I would rewrite the call signature so that it doesn't care about `Nodes` at all.  If you are expecting `node` to have a `title` property of type `string`, then that's all you need to say:

```
(node: {title: string}) => string;
```

Meaning:

```
function getTitleFromNode(node: { title: string }): string {
  return node.title
}
const branchNodeTitle = getTitleFromNode(branchNode) // okay
const branchNodeWithAdditionalTitle = getTitleFromNode(branchNodeWithAdditional) // okay
const leafNodeTitle = getTitleFromNode(leafNode) // okay
const leafNodeWithAdditionalTitle = getTitleFromNode(leafNodeWithAdditional) // okay
```

Maybe that doesn't meet your underlying use case, but in general: the simpler the better.  If you don't need [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) or generics, don't use them.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwCJuGgPACoB8UAvFIVBAB7AQoAmAzlAK5MQBmCKEjUAPxQA3gF8oALlFRGuNNKpiAUMtCQoAITTMIAOSSMIRUhRHKoURMAwRpzYACdeAc2USAZLHjJ02eSaq6tAGRsxE5OycPHyMplqOaCgAxgAWocYkUAA+UAAyEGhcGYFq4NCaiSnphpmRHEYx-PHauiVZXuaWKLXM0hnhJADaALruQeX5hcW1ERQN3LzNka36sySqyagOUABGVWkZ0pVJh7WRXVYINnZQAET7pzVGdwA0FlA9YdKj48pbKB2j2qGQA6tdUgBBRiMa6+TDHA7PYwoNgAW12EEc8Uu1ls0geSLBEOhsMQqEwbw+XwgfSgo3eljkeGkAEY-gCdrYikcpjzzmYPnjbnduTMXhztsAoGLicAoTC4RSMNICvyjPhURisTihdd8fdZbVwfLSUq-FSmfI2X8yhoYM4XJEiK8oHpqHQGCw3b0TMQABQ0-oASnIpAczhQLgA3HboABlNBoiCQ1gUfDu2j0JisAb4DgAax6AHcUMQA0G3aGyOGnK5Y8EoJCMMwkJFA7V+r7CyWy9Xa5GY6plFwOMlySgoC4IMBCPqIAAxRxINEZDtGaQiK43ex1qNQMTB3eD0QfRwztiOSc0gB0wvGnOlwLORjnN0i09n86XK7Xz+RoYAPSAVASAFmgID-FKexEsaJKKhOmBvrYH4zshi7LqutT+v+coKmS8IYEBIFgRBUGAtKRqvvOqFfjcP5YUY-pURAxGgeBkGPjK0x4WaiEYOhtHoQxa4sSa+HmpgbGkSAQA)